Is this `block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp` feasible since `block.timestamp` has been stored in variable lastTimeStamp`
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.19;

// AutomationCompatible.sol imports the functions from both ./AutomationBase.sol and
// ./interfaces/AutomationCompatibleInterface.sol
import {AutomationCompatibleInterface} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/automation/AutomationCompatible.sol";

/**
 * @dev Example contract, use the Forwarder as needed for additional security.
 *
 * @notice important to implement {AutomationCompatibleInterface}
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT THAT USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT THAT USES UN-AUDITED CODE.
 * DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */

contract Counter is AutomationCompatibleInterface {
    /**
     * Public counter variable
     */
    uint256 public counter;

    /**
     * Use an interval in seconds and a timestamp to slow execution of Upkeep
     */
    uint256 public immutable interval;
    uint256 public lastTimeStamp;

    constructor(uint256 updateInterval) {
        interval = updateInterval;
        lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;

        counter = 0;
    }

    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes calldata /* checkData */
    )
        external
        view
        override
        returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */)
    {
        upkeepNeeded = (block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval;
        // We don't use the checkData in this example. The checkData is defined when the Upkeep was registered.
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {
        if ((block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval) {
            lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        // We don't use the performData in this example. The performData is generated by the Automation Node's call to your checkUpkeep function
    }
}


Yes. For example: You deployed contract at block #999 with timestamp is 2024-01-01 => lastTimeStamp = 2024-01-01. And you execute perfomUpKeep at block #1500 with timestamp is 2024-02-01. Your operator will be: 2024-02-01 - 2024-01-01 = 30 days. It can work well I think

I still don't understand.

You can try hardhat, import "hardhat/console.sol" and log value of them to visualize

Yes, the approach is feasible, but it's important to note that block.timestamp can be slightly manipulated by Node. However, aside from that, the approach is generally fine.
